# How to simulate neural network by changing different parameters after training in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, networking, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have trained the neural network for a particular time series in MATLAB. After that I have saved the network. So if I want to simulate the network using different parameters like changing the number of neurons,number of hidden layer, transfer functions, learning ratio,momentum coefficient, Can I do it without again training the network? 
If not what is the criteria to select the best parameter for my neural network?
How should I configure my neural network in MATLAB to do all these?

Comment: No, the training is NN-structure dependent.

Answer (score 1):

No because you save whole model to file, with including weights + activation function and whole structure (layers). You can train few networks, and save to file if you want to check in future on real data (validation data) which networks is better.

Check this also ;) http://people.cs.umass.edu/~btaylor/publications/PSI000008.pdf